# Is it possible to modify libgdx's Table cells?

Tags: libgdx

I'm using libgdx [Table](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Table.html) to show some info. This information can change sometimes. I would like to change the cells so that they reflect the updated values. Is this possible or are `Tables` designed to be static? To clarify, I would like to do is something like this:

```
class MyTable extends Table{
    Cell<Label> cell;
    public MyTable(){
        super();
        cell = add("some value");
        // Add many more cells and rows here
    }

    public void updateCell(String val){
        cell.update(val); // How to do this??
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to do this *without* knowing the position of the changed cell, but any solution that requires that info is OK too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add("some value")` is a convenience method, which actually adds a `Label` with the given text.

You can achieve the same by doing this:

```
Label myLabel = new Label("some value", skin);
add(myLabel);
```

After that you can change the text by changing the label itself.

```
public void updateCell(String val){
    Label myLabel = (Label) cell.getActor();
    myLabel.setText(val);
}
```